# How to stop a foreground service before calling startForeground() method?

Tags: android

I am starting a foreground service using the following code

```
 if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
    context.startForegroundService(intent);
  } else {
    context.startService(intent);
  }
```

This starts a foreground service. In Android Oreo and above, we must call `startForeground()` method within 5 seconds. Now in my service, we do some processing and if certain conditions are not met, then I don't call `startForeground()` method. Instead, I try to kill the service.

```
 if (someConditionMet) {
        startForeground(notificationId, notification)
    } else {
        stopSelf()
 }
```

Now if `someConditionMet` variable is false, then my app crashes with the following crash log.

```
2019-04-10 16:57:25.695 19785-19785/com.awesomedroidapps.foregroundactivity E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.awesomedroidapps.foregroundactivity, PID: 19785
android.app.RemoteServiceException: Context.startForegroundService() did not then call Service.startForeground(): ServiceRecord{e78d43f u0 com.awesomedroidapps.foregroundactivity/.ForegroundServiceTest}
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1835)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6863)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:537)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
```

I don't understand that when I am stopping the service then why is it necessary to call `startForeground()` method? Is there any way we can stop the foreground service without calling `startForeground()` method?

Comment: Can you try adding stopForeground(true) and only then stopSelf() ?

Comment: tried this also. not working

Comment: AFAIK, there is no way around this. I suspect this restriction is in place to prevent developers to having what amounts to a long-running background service by having two services running alternately for a few seconds each.

Answer (score 0):

You can't. Period.

You can't stop a foreground service before the startForeground has been called and successfully executed. It is mandatory to finish this call before any action in the foreground service is taken. 
No matter what combinations of stopSelf() and stopForeground() you use, it would not do what you desire to do.
Here is a really nice article about the same:
[Foreground Service Pitfalls](https://proandroiddev.com/pitfalls-of-a-foreground-service-lifecycle-59f014c6a125)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to stop service without creating actual notification you can just invoke `startForeground` with stub notification and cancel in right after `stopSelf` is invoked.

```kotlin
if (conditionMet)
    startForeground(notificationId, notification)
} else {
    startForeground(STUB_NOTIFICATION_ID, createStubNotification())
    stopSelf()
    cancelStubNotification()
}
```

```kotlin
private fun createStubNotification(): Notification {
    val notificationManager =
        getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(
            NotificationChannel(
                STUB_NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID,
                STUB_NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_NAME,
                IMPORTANCE_LOW
            ).apply { setShowBadge(false) }
        )
    }
    return with(NotificationCompat.Builder(this, STUB_NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID)) {
        setBadgeIconType(NotificationCompat.BADGE_ICON_NONE)
        setOngoing(true)
        setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_notification)
        priority = NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_LOW
        setShowWhen(false)
        setSilent(true)
        build()
    }.also { notificationManager.notify(STUB_NOTIFICATION_ID, it) }
}
```

```kotlin
private fun cancelStubNotification() =
    (getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager)
        .cancel(STUB_NOTIFICATION_ID)
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this: Use a static variable and track the state of your service i.e running or not running, then check the state before calling `stopself()`. When the service is started, update the boolean flag to `true` and when it stops, update the boolean flag to `false`.

Comment: how is this going to solve the scenario which I mentioned?